# What's the best way to create a local server in order to use all the dependencies installed through NPM?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I've been struggling recently finding a fast and swift solution in order to create a local server and run my JavaScript project (with all the dependencies) in a browser. I've used WebPack in the past, despite is reliable and the local-server reflects immediately all the changes I make to the code, implementing it is cumbersome e requires a lot of time. Moreover creates a few compressed files that requires a bit to load. What are the alternatives or, more in general what it's used by developers to create projects and run it in a local server ? It's difficult once the project is complete to deploy it ?

I'm sorry if the question seem stupid, but I searched over and over, on YT, here on stack overflow, and I haven't found anything useful. I bet other junior devs stumped in a similar situation.

Comment: You could use a compiling tool to build and serve your project. You did not specify how you want your files to be compiles, so i can't help you with that. But you could use gulp along with [gulp-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-serve) to emulate a simple express server and run your files.

Comment: *what is used in the industry* Most of the time, you will use a framework and they usually come with a serve and compile solution out of the box. If you really wish to do this custom, which i do not recommend, you would need to do the exact same things as the frameworks do. create a few gulp ( or grunt ) task to compile you Js and it's dependencies, then run a simple server for developpement.

Comment: There is a bunch load of Javascript framework out there. I personnally love Angular, but it might not be appropriate for your use case. I suggest looking into the available framework and choose one that might be the best for you.

Comment: Keep in mind also that all of this is my personnal opinion. There is a lot of people that would disagree with me so take all of this with a grain of salt. You might want to check the pros and cons of a framework and make up your own mind before going foward

Comment: What code editor are you using?  Both VS Code and Atom have great live-server packages that will spin up a server and refresh with any changes.  Super easy to work with.  If you're working with any kind of compiled libraries (think React), you may need more than just a live server.  Webpack dev server is a good option to build your files and serve them locally.  There's also node HTTP server.

Comment: @SethLutske I'm using VS Code, I'll try using the live-server, though I'm not sure could work with NPM. Apart from Webpack dev server do you personally recommend me any other solution ?

Comment: Thank you@Nicolas, in fact I was thinking to use Angular too!

Comment: The live-server packages work fine with npm packages...I'm not sure what problems you're aniticpating using both together.  I use a lot of create-react-app, which has its own built in `npm start` script which will build the files and serve them up in your browser with live-refresh.  But that's only if you're making a react project.  You can accomplish the same thing with a webpack dev server, which I think is what create-react-app uses.  If you want super cheat mode, use codesandbox.io, at least for small projects or snippets.  Pretty amazing online IDE.